# Its saying segmentation fault when i call in the `inputmatrix` function. I made sure the array of pointers pointed to a valid memory space

Tags: c, parameter-passing

Im getting an error when i input the first matrix using the `inputmatrix` function. Am i passing the arguments incorrectly ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void inputmatrix(int *a[10],int m,int n)
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",(*(a+i) + j));
        }
    }
}

void multiplymatrix(int *a[10],int *b[10],int *c[10],int m1,int n2)
{
    int i,j,k,sum=0;

    for(i=0;i<m1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n2;j++)
        {
            for(k=0;k<n2;k++)
            sum += *(*(a+i)+k) * *(*(b+k)+i);
        }
        *(*(c+i)+j)=sum;
    }
}

void outputmatrix(int *c[10],int m1,int n2)
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<m1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n2;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",(*(c+i) + j));
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int a[10][10],b[10][10],c[10][10],m1,m2,n1,n2;

    printf("Enter the order of the first matrix : ");
    scanf("%d%d",&m1,&n1);

    printf("Enter the order of the second matrix : ");
    scanf("%d%d",&m2,&n2);

    if(n1==n2)
    {
        printf("Enter the first matrix : ");
        inputmatrix(a,m1,n1);

        printf("Enter the second matrix : ");
        inputmatrix(b,m2,n2);

        multiplymatrix(a,b,c,m1,n2);

        outputmatrix(c,m1,n2);
    }
}
```

Comment: you scan two int without separator ?? Why `int *` in `int *a[10]` ?

Comment: Activate your compiler warning you will get info, `scanf("%d",*( *(a+i) + j ));` the second arg is an `int`, scanf is waiting for an `int *`

Comment: @Ôrel Don't strictly need seperator. From the [scanf man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html): "Most conversions discard initial white space characters (the exceptions are noted below)"

Comment: `*( *(a+i) + j ))` Don't do that. Array indexing is spelled out this way: `a[i][j]`.

Comment: @orel it is not needed to have a separator between the two `%d` in the scanf because reading int/numbers. The problem is not here but dereferencing undefined address

Comment: Yesterday I edited a first time your question to remove half lines being empty from your code etc, and I warn you about that. You edited few mins ago your question and redo the same error as yesterday !

Comment: yeah im sorry the code was beautified by my editor. Can you please help

Comment: Please see my expanded answer.

Answer (score 0):

You *declared* the parameter `a` to your `inputmatrix` function as an array of 10 pointers to `int` – but you have not assigned any pointer values to it. As a result you're using random, unknown values of pointers, pointing anywhere, thus you triggered Undefined Behavior.

You're lucky the pointer you use apparently points to a not accessible area of memory, hence a Segmentation Violation. Otherwise your program could pretend it works correctly, and then spectacularly crash somewhere else...

**EDIT**

The actual error, however, is not missing the pointer initialization but rather ignoring the compiler's warning about passing an argument of incompatible type and, consequently, forcing a program to interpret as pointers data which were not pointers. I have tested the call line in the online GDB compiler at https://www.onlinegdb.com/ and it said:

> main.c:12:6: note: expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[10]’

The `a` variable in `main()` is an array 10 by 10, which is 100 `int` values stored in a contiguous block of memory. OTOH `inputmatrix` expects an array of 10 *pointers*, each pointing *somewhere else* to an `int` (or a block of `int` values).

The actual type of parameter passed to the function is not 'a 10-elements array of pointers to `int`', as you declared by `int *a[10]`, but rather 'a pointer to a 10-elements array of integers', which should be declared as `int (*a)[10]`.